# I have errors when I want to start react project

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite

I have created a new React project with Vite using `npm create vite@latest`. However, after running `npm install` and starting the project with `npm run dev`, I encounter the error below:

```bash
Error: Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-win32-x64-msvc. npm has a bug related to optional dependencies          (https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4828). Please try `npm i` again after removing both package-lock.json and node_modules directory.
    at requireWithFriendlyError (C:\vite-react-app\my-vite\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:64:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\vite-react-app\my-vite\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:73:48)
```

What could be the issue? I do not know the module `@rollup-win32-x4-msvc`. Should this module exist in the project?

Here is a picture of the errors I get from building the project.
[image]

Comment: Did you try doing what the error message said? _"Please try `npm i` again after removing both package-lock.json and node_modules directory"_

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```
npm install --save-dev "@rollup/rollup-win32-x64-msvc"
```

Answer (score -1):

In error mentioned doing this.

```
Please try npm i again after removing both the package-lock.json and node_modules directory.
```

I think you should try that, May it resolve the issue

Steps

1. Remove lock file and node_modules
2. Run command  `npm i`